# Problema con integración de Stripe con Laravel

Tags: laravel, stripe

Estoy creando una web con laravel y necesito integrar Stripe. Para ello estoy usando Cashier. He creado una suscripción anual, y al hacer las pruebas me da el siguiente error:

The payment attempt failed because of an invalid payment method.

El código que tengo en mi controlador es:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller; // Asegúrate de importar el Controller correcto

class SubscriptionController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('subscription.index');
    }

    public function subscribe(Request $request)
    {
        $user = $request->user();
        $paymentMethod = $request->input('payment_method');
        
        $user->createOrGetStripeCustomer();
        
        $user->newSubscription('default', 'price_1MtnSmCNGUc1AmzpWKEPyqYu')->create($paymentMethod, [
            'email' => $user->email,
        ]);
        
        return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with('success', '¡Te has suscrito correctamente!');
    }
}
```

Estoy usando las claves de prueba de stripe y las tarjetas de prueba que ellos te dan, por lo que el error no es del método de pago.

Solo quiero que me acepte el pago, ya que en stripe me registra como pago rechazado.